# Как добавить в Яндекс MapKit сотни меток с собственным изображением

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

помогите пожалуйста, как добавить в Яндекс MapKit сотни а то и больше меток  с собственным изображением, пишу на Android Studio, Java. Несколько дней подряд в инете ищу, ответа так и не нашёл, а в документации по поводу MapKit'a толком ничего не понял. Если можно с конкретными примерами помогите плес:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я писал эту обертку для себя. В целом то что вас интересует это addMarker. Надо добавить 100 маркеров, просто вызовите его 100 раз.

```
class YandexMapView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0,
    defStyleRes: Int = 0
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyle, defStyleRes) {

    private val yandexMap: MapView
    private var mapObjectCollection: MapObjectCollection
    private var markerTapListener: MapObjectTapListener? = null
    private val userLocation by lazy { getUserLocationLayer() }

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.map_view, this, true)
        yandexMap = mapView
        mapObjectCollection = yandexMap.map.mapObjects.addCollection()
    }

    fun onStart() {
        yandexMap.onStart()
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStart()
    }

    fun onStop() {
        yandexMap.onStop()
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().onStop()
    }

    fun release() {
        mapObjectCollection.clear()
        markerTapListener = null
    }

    fun setTapListener(listener: MapObjectTapListener) {
        markerTapListener = listener
    }

    fun showUserLocation() {
        userLocation.apply {
            isVisible = true
            isHeadingEnabled = false

            setAnchor(
                PointF((yandexMap.width * 0.5f), (yandexMap.height * 0.5f)),
                PointF((yandexMap.width * 0.5f), (yandexMap.height * 0.83f))
            )
            resetAnchor()
        }
    }

    fun moveAnimatedTo(
        latitude: Double,
        longitude: Double,
        zoom: Float = DEFAULT_ZOOM,
        azimuth: Float = 0F,
        tilt: Float = 0F,
        animation: Animation,
        callback: Map.CameraCallback? = null

    ) {
        yandexMap.map.move(
            CameraPosition(Point(latitude, longitude), zoom, azimuth, tilt),
            animation,
            callback
        )
    }

    fun addMarker(
        latitude: Double,
        longitude: Double,
        @DrawableRes imageRes: Int,
        userData: Any? = null
    ): PlacemarkMapObject {
        val marker = mapObjectCollection.addPlacemark(
            Point(latitude, longitude),
            ImageProvider.fromResource(context, imageRes)
        )
        marker.userData = userData
        markerTapListener?.let { marker.addTapListener(it) }
        return marker
    }

    fun getZoom() = yandexMap.map.cameraPosition.zoom

    private fun getUserLocationLayer() =
        MapKitFactory.getInstance().createUserLocationLayer(yandexMap.mapWindow)

    companion object {

        const val DEFAULT_ZOOM = 10F

        fun initialize(context: Context, apiKey: String) {
            MapKitFactory.setApiKey(apiKey)
            MapKitFactory.initialize(context)
        }
    }
}
```

В вашем Fragment/Activity это должно работать примерно так

```
//Маркеры в Yandex MapKit имеют WeakReference. И ссылки на них будут уничтожаться постоянно сборщиком мусора. Так что если вы хотите взаимодействовать с вашими маркерами, их надо хранить ручками. Например так
private val markerDataList = HashMap<Data, PlacemarkMapObject>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    YandexMapView.initialize(requireContext(), apiKey)
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    yandexMap.onStart()
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    yandexMap.onStop()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    yandexMap?.release()
}

private fun addMarkers(dataList: List<Data>) {
    for (data in dataList) {
        val marker = yandexMap.addMarker(
            latitude = data.latitude,
            longitude = data.longitude,
            imageRes = R.drawable.ic_marker,
            userData = data.tag
        )
        //Вот здесь я как раз и сохраняю каждый маркер в свою мапу
        markerDataList[data] = marker
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не знаю что ещё можно показать пошагово.