# Ошибка setApiKey() у яндекс карт

Tags: java, android, flutter, yandexmapkit

Иногда приходит ошибка:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError: setApiKey() should be called before initialize()!

При использовании Яндекс карт, но не знаю почему.
Пакет Яндекса форкнул и сделал вот так внутри пакета в андроид части:

```java
public void onAttachedToEngine(FlutterPluginBinding binding) {
    MapKitFactory.setApiKey("KEY");
    MapKitFactory.setLocale("eu_EU");
    MapKitFactory.initialize(binding.getApplicationContext());
    BinaryMessenger messenger = binding.getBinaryMessenger();
    binding.getPlatformViewRegistry().registerViewFactory(VIEW_TYPE, new YandexMapFactory(messenger, new LifecycleProvider()));

    setupChannels(messenger, binding.getApplicationContext());
  }
```

Но все равно ловлю эту ошибку.

Comment: Похоже [это](https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/issues/221#issuecomment-954451998) должно помочь. Инициализацию нужно выносить.

Comment: Вот, например, посмотрите как в [в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1092387/531666) делают инициализацию. (не дубликат)

Comment: @DiMithras, спасибо, попробую!

Comment: Если всё получится, можно оформить в ответ

Comment: все равно иногда проскакивает ошибка, скорее всего где-то кэшируется, спасибо за помощь!